# Zapier gives error: `'unicode' object has no attribute 'copy'` for Python script

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, datetime, zapier

The script is simple:

```
import datetime
import json

today = datetime.date.today()
next_thursday = today + datetime.timedelta(((3 - today.weekday()) % 7))
while True:
    if 15 <= next_thursday.day <= 21:
        next_third_thursday = next_thursday
        break
    else:
        next_date = next_thursday + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        next_thursday = next_date + datetime.timedelta(((3 - next_date.weekday()) % 7))

return json.dumps({'date': str(next_third_thursday)})
```

[image]

How do I get this code to run? What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

Zapier expects the output of the script to be a JSON-serializable object (h/t to Michael Case from the comments section).

Furthermore, the script is not indented properly. Python is an indentation-sensitive language, i.e. indentation matters.

Try something like this:

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
next_thursday = today + datetime.timedelta(((3 - today.weekday()) % 7))
while True:
    if 15 <= next_thursday.day <= 21:
        next_third_thursday = next_thursday
        break
    else:
        next_date = next_thursday + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        next_thursday = next_date + datetime.timedelta(((3 - next_date.weekday()) % 7))

return {'date': str(next_third_thursday)}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think you might also need to indent the code properly.

Comment: silly me. I did indent the code but pasted it without the indentations by mistake.

unfortunately... your updated answer still returns the same error. :( ugh. so frustrating.

Comment: oh, and the error return just shows the code unindented, but it is properly indented when run.

Comment: Milan's answer is close. The issue here is that json.dumps serializes your object converting it into a string. So in this example you are still returning a string which is why you are receiving the same error. With Zapier's code module you need to return a dictionary object which Zapier automatically maps to JSON format for use in later steps. In this case remove the json.dumps line and simply return the dictionary object.

Comment: I have updated Milan's answer to so that is produces the desired result for anyone who may come across it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the update Michael. It was rejected while I was sleeping, but I've updated the answer now.